# What is the possible impact of inserting user input into image src?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, html

A website takes user input and pass into img src. What is the possible impact that I can do with it?

`<img src="https://website.com/static/{user-input}">`

I did think of some options:

- Testing for XSS
- Logout CSRF: `website.com/static/../logout`
- Is open redirect possible by doing something like `website.com/static/@//google.com` ??

I wonder what is more to it?

Comment: What about `doesnotexist" onerror="XSS.js`?

Comment: Or "**../../mysite.org**"

Comment: @MechMK1 I tried it, but " is escaped. I tried with unicode normalization too, but no luck.

Comment: @user10216038, in this case, it will become website.com/mysite.org, and mysite.org is understood as a path in url, not a domain.

Comment: In the news:  **Apache fixes actively exploited web server zero-day** https://therecord.media/apache-fixes-actively-exploited-web-server-zero-day/ . *“An attacker could use a path traversal attack to map URLs to files outside the expected document root,” *. **Example:** *https://HOST/xx/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/etc/passwd*.